# Solutions to Introduction to applied linear algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I started learning linear algebra by reading Introduction to applied linear algebra book:

http://vmls-book.stanford.edu/

great book but there are no solutions for exercises. Where can I find exercises with solutions for linear algebra?

Thank you in advance,
Milan

Comment: Very good question: I get the fact that this is not a pure "math" question but given the audience, posting the question here is a good way to potentially get an answer. Thanks a lot to Prof Boyd and Prof Vandenberghe to make their high quality book free online. However for the ones (like me) who (try to) learn the subject by themselves and not have time/money to go to Stanford, trying to solve the exercices without the solutions is useless. Posting the probable answer and hoping to get corrected is not feasible neither because highly inefficient

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the solutions aren't published. However, you may ask **specific** questions about one particular problem and SE Mathematics might answer.